# Rakuten - window.DataLayer.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'am trying to push datalayer on my rakuten traking but I am getting the below error

window.dataLayer.push is not a function

Please my code below.

```
//START Rakuten Marketing Tracking 
    (function (url) {
      /*Tracking Bootstrap Set Up DataLayer objects/properties here*/
      if(!window.DataLayer){
        window.DataLayer = {};
      }
      if(!DataLayer.events){
        DataLayer.events = {};
      }
      DataLayer.events.SPIVersion = DataLayer.events.SPIVersion || "3.4.1";
      DataLayer.events.SiteSection = "1";

      var loc, ct = document.createElement("script");
      ct.type = "text/javascript";
      ct.async = true; ct.src = url; loc = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      loc.parentNode.insertBefore(ct, loc);
      }(document.location.protocol + "//tag.rmp.rakuten.com/xxxxxx.ct.js"));
// END Rakuten Marketing Tracking 
      
      
    window.DataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      window.DataLayer.push({
     'event': 'internet',
     'typeofBusinessSolution': 'internet'
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Rakuten, but I see some errors in the code.

1. `Datalayer.events` is defined as an Object, but used as an array. You could change that this way:

```
if(!DataLayer.events){
    DataLayer.events = [];
}
```

2. You try to push to dataLayer directly. The code above says it should be the `events`, right? This change could help:

```
window.DataLayer = window.dataLayer || {};
window.DataLayer.events = window.dataLayer.events || [];
window.DataLayer.events.push({
    'event': 'internet',
    'typeofBusinessSolution': 'internet'
});
```